# Difference between Spline and Piecewise Regression

Tags: regression, splines, piecewise-linear

I was looking for the difference between spline regression and piecewise regression. Can someone please explain it to me? Also, if someone can provide me good reference on these 2 topics, with implementation in either R or Python, that would be very helpful.

Comment: See also this question https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/590959/16974 which includes several references, including a paper on spline implementation in R https://bmcmedresmethodol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12874-019-0666-3 (I use the rms::rcs function).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here are some of the differences

- Piecewise regression yields continuous functions which are not, generally, differentiable and hence not smooth.
- Regression with splines yields *smooth* continuous functions.  The degree of smoothness will depend on what kind of spline you use, but cubic splines are differentiable at least twice.

Good references include Frank Harrell's *Regression Modelling Strategies*.  Libraries in R include `{splines}` or the `{rms}` library.  In particular, the `{splines}` library can expand predictors into a linear and cubic spline basis through use of the `degree` argument in the `bs` function.  It is worthwhile to note that piecewise regression is just spline regression where the basis functions are linear polynomials as opposed to cubic or restricted cubic polynomials.

Here is an example of using the `splines` library.

```r
library(splines)


x <- runif(100)
y <- sin(2*pi*x) + rnorm(100, 0, 0.3)

xx <- seq(0, 1, 0.01)

fit1 <- lm(y~bs(x, degree=1, df=4))
fit2 <- lm(y~bs(x, degree=3, df=4))


plot(x, y, pch=19)
lines(xx, predict(fit1, newdata=list(x=xx)), col='red')
lines(xx, predict(fit2, newdata=list(x=xx)), col='blue')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please confirm if using these 2 R packages can we do both piecewise and spline regression or does they support only spline regression? Thanks!

Comment: @ragas both should be able to do spline and piecewise regression (since one is a special case of the other using a basis comprised of degree 1 polynomials).  See my included example.

Comment: I think your answer should make this more explicit

Comment: Thanks Demetri! Your answer complete in every respect.

Comment: @seanv507 I've added some clarity